# If there is no value, update if there is an insert value

Tags: sql, postgresql, mybatis

I am using postgresql 9.4.1212. I am writing myBatis query, but I do not know.
Can I get help?

Here is my query code:

```
insert into search_by_date (date,total_count) values (#{date},#{total});
```

The parameter is map, and if there is an value, I want to update

here my search_by_date table..

```
column= > no(serial primary key) , date varchar(50),total_count(int)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

Comment: i do not know... sorry because i'm newbi..

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for in an Upsert operation. It will be a feature in PostgreSQL 9.5

You can implement it by making a function to do just the same, first check the number of rows that match. If 0 then insert if greater update

Answer (score 0):

Create a Unique index on the group of columns which you need to update on conflict.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_dt_ct ON search_by_date USING BTREE(date,total_count) ;
```

While Inserting use ON CONFLICT clause on the columns specified in the index.

```
    INSERT INTO search_by_date(date,total_count)
      VALUES( '02-05-2017'::DATE , 50 )
       ON CONFLICT(date,total_count)  
    DO UPDATE SET date = EXCLUDED.date, total_count = EXCLUDED.total_count;
```